# JQuery droppable out event triggers too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-draggable, jquery-droppable

I am using JQuery droppable container for dropping other elements. A added hoverClass when users mouse is over the container. In this class I set new width of the container. But this new width in not considered when mouse is leaving the container. Out event is triggered as container would have old width. What is even more strange is that if I move dragging element very slowly that new width of container is considered.

I have made the fiddle example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SLGdE/709/

Tested in Chrome and FF.

How can I achieve that new width of droppable container is considered?

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
      revert:true
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        tolerance: "pointer",
        hoverClass: "over"
    });
});
```

Comment: encountered the same problem, how did you manage to solve yours?

Comment: I solved this by manually checking  while dragging, if still over the droppable element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `refreshPositions` with value `true` to your `draggable`.  Note, however, that there will be a performance hit per https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions.  So it is likely that your workaround is a better option, but maybe this answer could help someone else.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    revert:true, 
    refreshPositions: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class and customize it. From jQueryUi [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/):

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
  }
});
```

Comment: This problem occurs before dropping the element. Problem is on events "over" and "out".

Comment: Ok. I have just understood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/SLGdE/710/ :

```
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({revert:true});
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    hoverClass: "over",
    over:function(event, ui){
        $(this).width($(this).width());//This is the update
    },
    out:function(event, ui){
        //alert("out")        
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Out event still triggers too early. You can see that, because color changes back to red. And the width is not reverted, when leaving container.